# Checking Map Being Holomorphic, using Cauchy-Riemann Equation

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surface by Rick Miranda. And I was doing the exercise at the end of the first section. I let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. Andd I have $U$ be any subset of $X$. I define a chart $$\phi_{U}(x,y) = \frac{x}{1+ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} + i \frac{y}{1 + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$. I need to prove that any two charts defined like this are compatible. In this case, I need to show that $\phi_{U} \circ \phi_{U}^{-1}$ is holomorphic. Then I tried to first compute the four partial derivatives to use Cauchy-Riemann equation. I have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{1+\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}{(1+ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})^2}$$And we also have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}{(1+ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})^2}$$Then I have $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{1+\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}{(1+ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})^2}$$ And we have $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}{(1+ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})^2}$$ But from my computation so far, I can only conclude that it satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation only when $x = y$. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my proof so far? Thanks so much!
**UPDATE** So we let $z = x+iy$. Then we have $\phi_{U} \circ \phi_{U}^{-1} = z$, according to the definition of inverse function. Thus, it must be holomorphic. Then according to the definition, any two charts defined like this are compatible with each other.

Comment: So what are $u$ and $v$ here? The real and imaginary parts of $\phi_U$?

Comment: Also, what you need to check is that the composition $\phi_U \circ \phi_V^{-1}$ is holomorphic on the overlaps, for any two charts $\phi_U$ and $\phi_V$ defined as above. This does not necessarily mean that $\phi_U$ was holomorphic in the first place.

Comment: But here I cannot identify what $\phi_{U}$ and $\phi_{V}$ here is. I think they are the same expression, aren’t they?  @MathsMatador

Comment: And yeah $u$ and $v$ here mean the real and imaginary part of the expression @MathsMatador

Comment: They are indeed the same expression, simply defined on (possibly) different non-empty open sets $U, V$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Without knowing what the precise exercise is, I would hazard to guess that you need to show that for any non-empty open set $U$, $\phi_U$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. For then on the overlaps, as $\phi_U$ and $\phi_V$ are the same expressions, $\phi_U \circ \phi_V^{-1}$ is just the identity $z \mapsto z$, which is clearly holomorphic.

Comment: @MathsMatador Thank you for your comments! I've updated my post.